# Adding PSCustom Object to an array

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I'm using a double for-loop in order to list all the Teams' channels as well as their type in order to export them in a CSV:

```
$TeamsPool = Get-Team | Select DisplayName,GroupID # Existing Teams
$Report = @() # Final Report

foreach($team in $TeamsPool)
{
    $TeamsChannel = @{} | Select Teams,Channel,Type
    $TeamsChannel.Teams = $team.DisplayName
    $teamschannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupID
    foreach($Channel in $teamschannels)
    {
        $TeamsChannel.Channel=$Channel.DisplayName
        $TeamsChannel.Type=$Channel.MembershipType
        $Report+=$TeamsChannel
    }
}
```

The code works fine on Teams with a single channel, but as soon as there's more than a single channel, all values within "$Report" for that Teams get replaced by the last one:

Expected Result:

| Teams | Channel | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teams 1 | General | Public |
| Teams 1 | Public Channel 1 | Public |
| Teams 2 | General | Public |
| Teams 2 | Public Channel 2 | Public |
| Teams 2 | Private Channel 2 | Private |

Actual Result:

| Teams | Channel | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Teams 1 | Public Channel 1 | Public |
| Teams 1 | Public Channel 1 | Public |
| Teams 2 | Private Channel 2 | Private |
| Teams 2 | Private Channel 2 | Private |
| Teams 2 | Private Channel 2 | Private |

There seems to be a special interraction when adding PSCustomObject to Arrays, but I haven't been able to find out which.

Comment: build a `[PSCustomObject]` in the inner loop, not part in the outer and part in the inner. also, using `+=` on an array gets slower as the array grows. just assign the output loop to `$Report`, skip defining a blank `$Report`, and send the `PSCO`  out from the inner loop to be captured when all the loops finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently creating one output object *per team*, instead of *per channel* - so you end up overwriting the details of the previous output object when you hit the last channel.

Change your code to:

```
$TeamsPool = Get-Team | Select DisplayName,GroupID # Existing Teams
$Report = @() # Final Report

foreach($team in $TeamsPool)
{
    $teamschannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupID
    foreach($Channel in $teamschannels)
    {
        # Create new object per-channel
        $TeamsChannel = @{} | Select Teams,Channel,Type

        $TeamsChannel.Teams = $team.DisplayName
        $TeamsChannel.Channel=$Channel.DisplayName
        $TeamsChannel.Type=$Channel.MembershipType

        $Report += $TeamsChannel
    }
}
```

---

My personal preference would be to use `[pscustomobject]` over `select`, and assigning the whole loop expression to `$Report` instead of `+=`:

```
$TeamsPool = Get-Team | Select DisplayName,GroupID # Existing Teams

$Report = foreach($team in $TeamsPool)
{
    $teamschannels = Get-TeamChannel -GroupId $team.GroupID
    foreach($Channel in $teamschannels)
    {
        # Create new object per-channel
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Teams = $team.DisplayName
            Channel = $Channel.DisplayName
            Type = $Channel.MembershipType
        }
    }
}
```